# install grub bootloader dynamically to multiple disks

Tags: debian, grub, debian-installer, preseed, debconf

I am trying to preseed installing grub dynamically with to two disks with an early_command. I am using IPXE. Here is the relevant part:

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
DISKA=$(realpath /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SuperMicro_SSD_* /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SATA_SSD_*|grep -o '/dev/sd[a-z]'|uniq|sort|head -n1); \
DISKB=$(realpath /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SuperMicro_SSD_* /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SATA_SSD_*|grep -o '/dev/sd[a-z]'|uniq|sort|head -n2|tail -1); \
if [ "${DISKA}" == "" ]; then DISKA="/dev/sda"; fi; \
if [ "${DISKB}" == "" ]; then DISKB="/dev/sdb"; fi; \
debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$DISKA $DISKB"; \
debconf-set partman-auto-raid/recipe "1 2 0 ext4 / ${DISKA}2#${DISKB}2 . 1 2 0 lvm - ${DISKA}4#${DISKB}4 ."; \
debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev "$DISKA $DISKB";
```

I tried the above with multiple variations (true, false) of the following and without them as well:

```
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false
```

I even tried it within the early_command:

```
debconf-set grub-installer/only_debian false; \
debconf-set grub-installer/with_other_os false;
```

Unfortunately the `Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk` dialog still showing up with the correct disk as shown below, so I need to confirm and continue. Can I preseed this automatically?

[image: Install GRUB to disk]

Answer (score 2):

Got it. I have to remove the double quotes from the lines:

```
debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$DISKA $DISKB"; \
debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev "$DISKA $DISKB";
```

to become:

```
debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$DISKA $DISKB"; \
debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev $DISKA $DISKB;
```

**EDIT**

after reboot I found out that grub was only installed on `/dev/sda` with the following command `dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings`, which returns:

```
ZRr=
`|f 
\|f1
GRUB 
Geom
Hard Disk
Read
 Error
```

running the same command on `/dev/sdb` returns nothing which means the first 512B of the disk are empty, so I had to install grub manually to `/dev/sdb` as follows:

```
# grub-install /dev/sdb
# dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sdb 2>/dev/null | strings
ZRr=
`|f 
\|f1
GRUB 
Geom
Hard Disk
Read
 Error
```

I still can't find a way to install grub in to two disks with the `early_command`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

it seems unti now the only workaround is to add the following two line to the `early_command`:

```
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule;\
db_fset grub-installer/bootdev seen true
```

so it becomes:

```
.....
debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev "$DISKA $DISKB";\
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule;\
db_fset grub-installer/bootdev seen true
```

I hope this will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is already reported in 2013. It seem that the dialog always shows up when using LVM and/or RAID.

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Bugs/GrubInstaller

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712907

Answer (score 0):

I found another (less ugly) workaround which is to add this line to the preseed:

```
d-i grub-installer/bootdev string /dev/sda
```

And then overwrite that config using debconf-set as detailed in your question. The grub installer honors whatever you set in debconf-set.

I'm not certain why this works, but it seems like having that line in the preseed, even if you overwrite it later, implies that the question has been seen, so you don't need:

```
db_fset grub-installer/bootdev seen true
```